# Ubuntu 20.10 (pop-os) keeps going into sleep after closing laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sleep

After I close and open my laptop (razer blade 15 base 2019) it keeps going back to sleep after about 15 seconds. It only happens if I close laptop, doesn't seem to be an issue if I actually press suspend button in "Power Off / Log Out".

I can briefly see some errors before it goes to sleep. It never happened in 18 or 19 versions.

[Photo with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nmdL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue. I was able to resolve by disabling suspend when the lid is closed. Not an ideal solution, but I haven't found a better one yet. Suspending through the desktop menu works fine.

My solution:

1. Install grub if not already installed:

   `sudo apt install grub-pc`
2. Edit some files:

   1. grub settings

      `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

      - Comment out the lines (by prepending #. was L10-11 for me) starting with:

        ```
          GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT 
          GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX
        ```
      - Add these lines:

        ```
          GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT =”button.lid_init_state=open” 
          GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”button.lid_init_state=open”
        ```
   2. ACPI settings

      `sudo vi /etc/default/acpi-support`

      - Comment out the line (by prepending #. was L59 for me) starting with:

        ```
          SUSPEND_METHODS
        ```
      - Add a line:

        ```
          SUSPEND_METHODS=”none”
        ```
   3. systemd login settings

      `sudo vi /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

      - Add a line:

        ```
          HandleLidSwitch=ignore
        ```
3. Reboot